# Is it okay if all the columns in a table are part of some unique key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

This is my database for a bus transportation system.

[image: database schema]

As you can see some tables have all columns part of a unique key/primary key, is this designed well?

Comment: Please provide the actual code instead of the screenshot of the code.

Comment: This question sounds like a code review.. So the question should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see any unique key containing all columns.

Comment: Please restate your Question.  It is worded like "all columns _in a single unique key_".  But I think you meant "every column is _in some unique key_.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing *a priori* wrong with all the columns being declared unique, either by themselves or in combination with other columns.

In the case of designing bus routes in particular, you might have a challenge with "circle" routes -- buses that follow a circle returning to their point of origin.  That might not be an issue for your particular application.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that. You need to model your database so it can solve the problem you have. If having a unique key with all columns solves your problem, you are good, and nothing prevents you from doing it.